# Can autotools Makefiles display commands they execute?

Tags: autotools, automake

I'm trying to build a project, at-spi2-core and I'm getting undefined references. Obviously, x11 libraries are not being linked. However, I'd love to see what command makefile actually outputs. Now the output is like so:

```
  CCLD     at-spi2-registryd
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `find_display':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:83: undefined reference to `XextFindDisplay'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:83: undefined reference to `XextCreateExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:83: undefined reference to `XextAddDisplay'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `XTestCompareCursorWithWindow':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:136: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `XTestFakeKeyEvent':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:167: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `XTestFakeButtonEvent':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:188: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `XTestFakeMotionEvent':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:208: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `XTestFakeRelativeMotionEvent':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:234: undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o):/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:301: more undefined references to `XMissingExtension' follow
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/lib/libXtst.a(XTest.o): In function `close_display':
/home/deividas/Desktop/storage/Soft/MXE/mxe/tmp-xtst-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.static/libXtst-1.2.1/src/XTest.c:88: undefined reference to `XextRemoveDisplay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

CCLD is not helpful at all. I've tried stuff in http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Debugging-Make-Rules.html but nothing seems to output how ld is being performed. This section happens in inner folder of registryd and not in a root (if that's of any relevance). Did anyone have similar problem with getting normal debugging output with autotools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal makefiles always print out the commands they execute; `CCLD` and similar output are due to the Autotools "silent rules" feature. To disable it for one run of `make`, run `make V=1` (V stands for Verbose). To disable it permanently, run configure again with `--disable-silent-rules`.